# MUI Theme to control only <TextField color="primary"/> style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I would like to created a `<TextField color='primary'/>` with a global style on it. In stead of using styled-component, I think apply the style in MUI theme is a better way to control.

However, how can I only apply the style to `<TextField color='primary'/>` but not `<TextField color='secondary'/>`?

[SandBox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-gauss-incz40?file=/demo.tsx)

app.js

```
<TextField label="Primary Color" variant="outlined" /> {/* theme should be applied*/}
<TextField label="Secondary Color" variant="outlined" color="secondary" /> {/* theme should NOT be applied*/}
```

theme.js

```
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& label.Mui-focused": {
            color: "red"
          },
          "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
            borderBottomColor: "red"
          },
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            "& fieldset": {
              borderColor: "red"
            },
            "&:hover fieldset": {
              borderColor: "yellow"
            },
            "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
              borderColor: "red"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a function which checks for the `color === 'primary'` and only then applies the theme.

```
root: ({ ownerState, theme }) => ({
  ...(ownerState.color === "primary" && {
    "& label.Mui-focused": {
      color: "red"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "red"
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      "& fieldset": {
        borderColor: "red"
      },
      "&:hover fieldset": {
        borderColor: "yellow"
      },
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: "red"
      }
    }
  })
})
```

[Updated CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/theme-for-textfield-border-forked-2k5ucl)

You can read more about it here https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#overrides-based-on-props